# Regular Expression matching in ruby, checking for white space

Tags: ruby, regex, whitespace

I am trying to check a file for white spaces at the beginning of each line. I want the white-space at the beginning of the line to be consistent, all start with spaces or all start with tabs. I wrote the code below but it isn't working for me. If there exist a space at a beginning of one line and then a tab exists in the beginning of another line print a warning or something.

```
    file = File.open("file_tobe_checked","r")  #I'm opening the file to be checked 

    while (line = file.gets)

    a=(line =~ /^ /).nil?  
    b=(line =~/^\t/).nil?

    if  a==false && b==false
    print "The white spaces at the beginning of each line are not consistent"
    end 

    end
    file.close
```

Answer (score 1):

This is one solution where you don't read the file or the extracted lines array twice:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
file = ARGV.shift
tabs = spaces = false
File.readlines(file).each do |line|
  line =~ /^\t/ and tabs = true
  line =~ /^ / and spaces = true
  if spaces and tabs
    puts "The white spaces at the beginning of each line are not consistent."
    break
  end
end
```

Usage:

```
ruby script.rb file_to_be_checked
```

And it may be more efficient to compare lines with these:

```
  line[0] == "\t" and tabs = true
  line[0] == ' ' and spaces = true
```

You can also prefer to use `each_line` over `readlines`. Perhaps `each_line` allows you to read the file line by line instead of reading all the lines in one shot:

```
File.open(file).each_line do |line|
```

Comment: I was assuming he meant a line with a beginning space followed by the next line with a tab, but I could be wrong.

Comment: It is a she :) No I just want to check the beginning of the line. I don't really care what character is following the white space at the beginning of the line.

Answer (score 0):

How important is it that you check for the whitespace (and warn/notify accordingly)? If you are aiming to just correct the whitespace, `.strip` is great at taking care of errant whitespace.

```
 lines_array = File.readlines(file_to_be_checked)

 File.open(file_to_be_checked, "w") do |f|
    lines_array.each do |line|
      # Modify the line as you need and write the result
      f.write(line.strip)
    end
 end
```

Comment: I just wanted to warn the user then they get to choose what ever they want to do, but thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I assume that no line can begin with one or more spaces followed by a tab, or vice-versa.

To merely conclude that there are one or more inconsistencies within the file is not very helpful in dealing with the problem. Instead you might consider giving the line number of the first line that begins with a space or tab, then giving the line numbers of all subsequent lines that begin with a space or tab that does not match the first line found with such.  You could do that as follows (sorry, untested).

```
def check_file(fname)
  file = File.open(fname,"r") 
  line_no = 0
  until file.eof?
    first_white = file.gets[/(^\s)/,1]
    break if first_white
    line_no += 1
  end
  unless file.eof?
    puts "Line #{line_no} begins with a #{(first_white=='\t') ? "tab":"space"}"    
    until file.eof?
      preface = file.gets[/(^\s)/,1))]
      puts "Line #{line_no} begins with a #{(preface=='\t') ? "tab":"space"}" \
        if preface && preface != first_white
      line_no += 1
    end
  end
  file.close
end
```